# iOSアプリのデバッグ時の実機挙動と未デバッグ時の実機での挙動の違いについて

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode7および6.4、端末はiOS7〜iOS9で起こったトラブルで質問させていただきます。

[CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket)というライブラリを用いてソケット通信を行っているのですが、MacとiPhoneを繋いだ実機デバッグでは、ソケットが何時間経過してもソケット通信でデータが送信されるのですが、
Macと繋がずに実機で確認してみると1分後にソケットが送られなくなるという挙動がでてしまうというトラブルに見舞われています。

ライブラリのタイムアウト設定が問題なのかと思い、タイムアウト設定を解除してみてもそのままでした。

このようなデバッグ時の実機挙動とデバッグなしの実機の挙動が違うというトラブルが起こった方はおりますでしょうか。

解決策など有りましたらご教示いただけると幸いです。

Comment: 上記ですが、多数ソケットを張っていましたので、UI更新部分のみメインスレッドにし、他はサブスレッドで実行することにより解決しましたが、デバッグ時のみこのような挙動になるのが本当に謎です。。。